# Screencapture.screenshot image does not look like screen. It is translucent when displayed (Unity 3D, Android)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, image-processing, textures, screen-capture

[Edited to provide additional info/partial answer at bottom]

Any constructive ideas on how to approach de-bugging this problem are appreciated.

I followed this tutorial on taking and displaying a screenshot using Unity's Screencapture.Capturescreenshot() method. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQeylS0l4S4&t=92s

On display, my screenshot image (a basic cube in 3D space) appears translucent. Does anyone have any idea why and how I can fix it so it shows a true screen shot? I used another phone to take a picture of my actual screen when I'm taking the screen shot here (Sorry it's a little blurry; the cube is moving):
[image: Actual screen image]

And a picture of the displayed screen shot. Notice how translucent it is:
[image: Screen capture image]

```
This is code to capture the screen image:
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 public class TakeScreenshot : MonoBehaviour {
 
     public void TakeAShot()
     {
         StartCoroutine ("CaptureIt");
     }
 
     IEnumerator CaptureIt()
     {
         string timeStamp = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
         string fileName = "Screenshot" + timeStamp + ".png";
         string pathToSave = fileName;
         ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(pathToSave);
         yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
     }
 
 }
```

And here is the code for displaying. It converts the .png file to a texture, makes a sprite out of the texture, and displays the sprite on the canvas. My canvas is set to default parameters in the inspector.

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using System.IO;
 
 public class ScreenshotPreview : MonoBehaviour {
     
     public GameObject canvas;
     string[] files = null;
     int whichScreenShotIsShown= 0;
 
     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {
         files = Directory.GetFiles(Application.persistentDataPath + "/", "*.png");
         if (files.Length > 0) {
             GetPictureAndShowIt ();
         }
     }
 
     void GetPictureAndShowIt()
     {
         string pathToFile = files [whichScreenShotIsShown];
         Texture2D texture = GetScreenshotImage (pathToFile);
         Sprite sp = Sprite.Create (texture, new Rect (0, 0, texture.width, texture.height),
             new Vector2 (0.5f, 0.5f));
         canvas.GetComponent<Image> ().sprite = sp;
     }
 
     Texture2D GetScreenshotImage(string filePath)
     {
         Texture2D texture = null;
         byte[] fileBytes;
         if (File.Exists (filePath)) {
             fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes (filePath);
             texture = new Texture2D (2, 2, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
             texture.LoadImage (fileBytes);
         }
         return texture;
     }
 }
```

---

Additional information:

So my thinking was that the problem had to either be in the capturing or the displaying. I realized I could look at the saved .png file in my Android files to see what they looked like before they are pulled back into the app for display.

The result? :  The .png looks perfect. So it's just a problem with the displaying. I still haven't solved the whole problem but now I know the screen is being captured perfectly with Unity's Screencapture.Capturescreenshot method.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the 'alpha' value for my panel in the second scene was at about 50%, which in alpha values is about 127.  To display the image exactly as it was taken on the screen, alpha needs to be at 255 , which represents 0% transparency. In general, many people want UI elements to have a degree of transparency so that you can see the main scene behind the UI elements. However, for viewing the screenshot I wanted no transparency. Therefore => Select the Panel in your hierarchy. Go to the Color quality in the Inspector. Double-click. Then set the Alpha value to 255.

If you have a situation where you do not have a dedicated scene just for viewing your screenshot and you want the alpha value to change within a single scene, you can change it using a script. In my case I could set my alpha to 255 permanently because the only purpose for that scene, and in fact the only purpose for that panel, was to display screenshots.
[image: Alpha value of Panel]